# How to grab specific text from a span given a specific heading

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags

I'm trying to parse a website and grab what're called PSC codes from it. The website structures the PSC codes like this:

```
<span class="results_title_text">PSC (Code): </span>
</td>
<td width="30%">
<span class="results_text">
                MED &amp; SURGICAL INSTRUMENTS,EQ &amp; SUP
                (
                                  <a alt="Click here to drill down by PSC Code 6515" href="?q=60854+PRODUCT_OR_SERVICE_CODE%3A%226515%22&amp;s=FPDS.GOV&amp;templateName=1.5.1&amp;indexName=awardfull&amp;x=0&amp;y=0" title="Click here to drill down by PSC Code  6515">6515</a>
                )
                </span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

So far I have written code that finds the span with the text "PSC (Code): ", but now I am unsure how to get to the next span that contains the actual PSC code. Here's what I have so far:

```
html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, features='lxml')
#print(soup)
span = soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'results_title_text'})
for s in span:
    if s.text == 'PSC (Code): ':
        print(s)
```

This code just prints "PSC (Code): " everywhere it's found in the html. Any thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: Will The span *enclosing* the link always be `class="results_text"`?

Comment: yes, it will always be listed like that.

Comment: Have you tried anything? SO isn't a code writing service - if you get yourself acquainted with beautiful soup you'll be able to write this yourself quickly. Please refer to [find_all](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all)

Comment: Hi I do have some code written but it have minimal functionality. I will rewrite the question with my code

Comment: What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: you didn't add url so we can't see this page but if page uses JavaScript to add elements then you can't get them with `urllib`/`requests` and `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml` because they can't run `JavaScript. You may  need `Selenium` to control web browser which can run `JavaScript.

Comment: if you have to check if text is `'PSC (Code): '` then get all `<span>` without using `class` - `find_all("span")` and then check `if span[0] == 'PSC (Code): '` and then get `span[1]`, `span[2]`, ect. - `span[1:]`

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to search the *soup*. Assuming the links with the codes are sufficiently similar you can use regular expression searches:

```
>>> import re
>>> soup.find(title=re.compile(r'PSC Code')).text
'6515'
>>> soup.find(href=re.compile(r'PRODUCT_OR_SERVICE_CODE')).text
'6515'
>>> soup.find('a',href=re.compile(r'PRODUCT_OR_SERVICE_CODE')).text
'6515'
>>> soup.find('a',title=re.compile(r'PSC Code')).text
'6515'
>>>
```

You would use [`.find_all`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree) and iterate over the result, if there were more than one in the content.

Answer (score 0):

Using `BeautifulSoup`, you can take a look at the `find_next` and the `find_all_next` methods.

```
span = soup.find("span", {"class": "results_title_text"})
if span.text.strip() == "PSC (Code):":
    l_other = span.find_all_next(string=True)
    for l in l_other:
        print(l)
```

The result would be

```
                MED & SURGICAL INSTRUMENTS,EQ & SUP
                (

6515

                )
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
html = '''<td><span class="results_title_text">PSC (Code): </span>
</td>
<td width="30%">
<span class="results_text">
                MED &amp; SURGICAL INSTRUMENTS,EQ &amp; SUP
                (
                                  <a alt="Click here to drill down by PSC Code 6515" href="?q=60854+PRODUCT_OR_SERVICE_CODE%3A%226515%22&amp;s=FPDS.GOV&amp;templateName=1.5.1&amp;indexName=awardfull&amp;x=0&amp;y=0" title="Click here to drill down by PSC Code  6515">6515</a>
                )
                </span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
span = doc.getElementByClass('results_title_text') # use class
span = doc.getElementByText('PSC (Code):',tag='span') # use text
print (span.text)

nextSpan = span.getParent().getNexts()[0].span # Through parent-child structure
print (nextSpan.html)

nextSpan = doc.getElementByClass('results_text',start='class="results_title_text"') # Through class and location
print (nextSpan.html)
```

The result would be

```
PSC (Code):
MED &amp; SURGICAL INSTRUMENTS,EQ &amp; SUP
                (
                                  <a alt="Click here to drill down by PSC Code 6515" href="?q=60854+PRODUCT_OR_SERVICE_CODE%3A%226515%22&amp;s=FPDS.GOV&amp;templateName=1.5.1&amp;indexName=awardfull&amp;x=0&amp;y=0" title="Click here to drill down by PSC Code  6515">6515</a>)
```